# How can I connect django to mqtt broker?

Tags: django, mqtt

I need to send some data from django wed server to board (esp8266), using MQTT protocol.
I have problems with finding information about how to connect django and mqtt-broker. How can I implement this?

Comment: This question is far to vague and broad to get a proper answer. Please read the [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on what a good question needs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your **MQTT Broker** you can choose between using a cloud provider or running a local broker.
Cloud providers include:

- Aws IoT (https://aws.amazon.com/iot-core/getting-started/)
- Google Cloud IoT Broker
  (https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/quickstart)

These services have step-by-step guides on how to configure your board to communicate with the broker and you can test this communication with the web console. Most cloud providers have a free tier so that you can test the services without cost.

If you prefer to run a **local broker, Mosquitto** (https://mosquitto.org/) is a very good option, with plenty of documentation and tutorials online. There is also a test server available here: https://test.mosquitto.org/

For your **django application** to communicate with the board, you need to run an MQTT client such as paho-mqtt (https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/).
Here is an example on how to use the client from the paho-mqtt documentation:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))

    # Subscribing in on_connect() means that if we lose the connection and
    # reconnect then subscriptions will be renewed.
    client.subscribe("$SYS/#")

# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(msg.topic+" "+str(msg.payload))

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message

client.connect("mqtt.eclipse.org", 1883, 60)

# Blocking call that processes network traffic, dispatches callbacks and
# handles reconnecting.
# Other loop*() functions are available that give a threaded interface and a
# manual interface.
client.loop_forever()
```